# NetFlow, count min, median, and max number of bytes per flow

Tags: netflow, silk

I have captured `.silk` file.

Is it possible to count min, median, and max number of bytes per flow using SiLK utils?

If yes, could you please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this? `rwstats --overall-stats filename.silk`

Comment: Yeah, that was the answer to my question. Thanks :)